# how to run server side exe file from classic asp for non IE browser

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

can any body tell me how to run server side exe with parameters from classic asp(vbscript) with non Internet Explorer browser (chrome and firefox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your browser doesn't have anything to do with that, as this is server-side. On the server , you could try this :

```
<%
Set WshShell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "c:\windows\notepad.exe"
Set WshShell= nothing
%>
```

It rings a bell to me, but I haven't used classic asp for years so it would need to be cheked.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I try the same and not working on NON IE browser, but yes work on IE

Comment: This should be executed server-side. The browser shouldn't have any impact on this... Are you using your locale machine to test ?

Comment: I'm not sure but this may have an impact. Could you try on a remote machine ? once again unless configured that way server-side code shouldn't be impacted by your client browser, especially that code which doesn't rely on user input...

Comment: I think this issue is with windows server 2003, because at server 2008, it works on firefox also , but on server2003 it does not work , could you please guide what is the issue with server 2003