# call a c# console App from an asp classic Page

Tags: c#, asp-classic, console-application, html

It is possible to do this? I've been making some research but I haven't found anything about it.

My case: unfortunately, we create a solution for a customer in c# console app. but seems that he'll need to run this console app we just create directly from an ASP Classic web page

Comment: Define "run this".  If it needs to run on the server, then I imagine ASP Classic has some means of invoking a command-line executable.  If it needs to run on the client, then no, no web application technology can do that (short of installing more invasive plugins).  The user would need to download the executable and run it locally.

Comment: You can run a console app on the server (Process.Start), but how will you use the data on your asp page? Better just reuse the data/business logic into a new asp project.

Comment: the app just stores an xml file coming from the asp web page into sql server 2012 in a DB that we already have. And yes, there's no problem if the server runs this app

Comment: @HugoMedina: Where are you stuck then?  A quick Google search turned up this, as well as others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570063/how-to-run-server-side-exe-file-from-classic-asp-for-non-ie-browser